# Additive and Multiplicative Effects: Terminology

Tags: terminology, article-writing

I am trying to explain the relationship between several variables. The outcome of interest is $Y \in \mathbb{R}$, and the predictors of interest are $A  \in \mathbb{R}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

I think $A$ is described as having an additive effect on $Y$. Positive $A$ can modify a negative $Y$ to a positive $Y$. Negative $Y$ can modify a positive $Y$ to a negative $Y$.

I think $B$ is described as having a multiplicative effect on $Y$. If $Y$ is positive, $B$ can increase or decrease the magnitude, but not change sign. Same if $Y$ is negative.

I am trying to explain the above in words without using the terms additive and multiplicative (assuming I am using them correctly). I'm trying to write something to the effect of:

> positive $A$ "pushes" $Y$ "to the right", while negative $A$ "pushes" $Y$ "to the left." $B > 1$ "increases the magnitude" of $Y$; $B < 1$ "decreases the magnitude" of $Y$; $B$ cannot change the sign of $Y$.

using proper/academic terms. Hoping there is a proper way to say this.

Comment: Since $B$ is positive, do you mean $B < 1$ when you say "$B < 0$"?

Comment: yes, made correction